# How to correctly copy and paste info (charts,tables etc) from a webpage to excel via vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have a table on a webpage that I am trying to copy and paste into excel, correctly formatted. It comes out all of it in one column, no matter what I try to do to fix it.

I am able to copy it and paste it, it's just super incorrectly formatted. please help.

```
 a lot of stuff before this....


 lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   ' lastrow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row
    i = i + 1

For i = 3 To lastrow
        Set svalue1 = .getElementbyID("provideANumber")
            svalue1.Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value

    For Each eInput In .getElementsbyTagName("input")
            If eInput.getAttribute("value") = "ENTERit" Then
                eInput.Click

    Exit For

            End If
Next

             IE.Visible = True
Exit For
Next i
```

more stuff in between.....

'Copy and Paste Results into Excel

```
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A1:Z50") = ""
    Range("A1:Z150").Select

    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now)


    IE.ExecWB 17, 0 '//select all
    IE.ExecWB 12, 2 '//Copy Selection
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, displayasicon:=False



    Range("A1:Z100").Select
```

I expect it to show up similiarly to how it looks on the website, however, it shows up all together in one column (and not even legible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("A1:Z100") = ""
    Range("A1:Z100").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now) '//Loads



    IE.ExecWB 17, 0 '//select all from webpage
    IE.ExecWB 12, 2 '//Copy Selection



    Application.DisplayAlerts = False  '//Doesnt display alerts
    ActiveSheet.Paste


    Sheets("Sheet4").Select '//Selects sheet 4 again
    Range("A3:Q32").Select
    Selection.Copy

        'Creates a new sheet after & pastes content into it, formats

        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Selection.Columns.AutoFit
        Selection.rows.AutoFit
```

This code allowed me to copy and paste the data from the web page the way it's formatted on the web page